# How can I make a QtIFW installer call a utility shipped with the installer?

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer

I'm considering to port an existing C++-based installer to [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html). There are a couple of things in the existing installer which I'd rather not change or reimplement at this time, e.g. parsing a license key. Instead, I'd like to reuse some of the existing code and build a smallish (GUI-less) utility out of it and then have the QtIFW installer call that as needed.

It appears that [`installer.execute`](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#execute-method) could be used to call an external program - but is there a way to address a program which is not on the system yet but rather part of the installer? Maybe I could store the program to call as a resource and extract it to the temporary directory at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this can be achieved by shipping the utility to call as a resource. The resource can then be "extracted" at runtime by invoking the [`installer.performOperation`](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#performOperation-method) function with `Copy` (see the [list of operations](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html)), as in:

```
installer.performOperation("Copy", ["://myutility.exe", "/tmp"]);
```

This assumes that [`binarycreator`](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-tools.html#binarycreator) was called with the `-r` argument which references an XML file like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>myutility.exe</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Hi, How to execute this "installer.performOperation" in elevated /admin right mode